# How do I edit my bounty notice to remove typos?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This question has not received enough answers:

[How to get more co-operation from a teacher who discourages a student from asking questions to clear his confusion?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/3095/how-to-get-more-co-operation-from-a-teacher-who-discourages-a-student-from-askin/3347#3347)

I posted this bounty notice now:

> Whether or not becauae of the Indian context, this question has not received any answer in the firat 5 days and not more than 1 answer in these 6 days. So it is time to post a bounty. Answers are welcome from members all over the world!

It has 2 typos that I noted only after the bounty notice was posted. They don't affect the readability in context, **but typos slways look bad.**

How do I edit the bounty notice to correct these errors?

Related query: I access Stack Exchange sites in android phones and tablets where I scroll up and down the pages with my *left hand* on the left margin of the screen. The last time I posted a bounty it got awarded prematurely (very luckily, to the right and intended answer) when my finger hit the bounty icon while scrolling. **Doesn't the system software ask me for confirmation before awarding the bounty?** Note that I use the 'mobile page version' for Android browser.

So I request the following features if they are not already available:

(1) user who set the bounty should be allowed to edit out typos in the bounty notice at least within 10 minutes of posting, because typos look bad in the bounty notice and can even possibly (though not in my case) distort the message or confuse the reader.

(2) the system should ask to confirm as in,

> ***are you sure you want to award the bounty to user123456?***

before finalizing the award of a bounty.

Comment: Related, on Meta Stack Exchange: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112188/274942

Comment: Thanks for the link to the earlier meta question, @HDE226868 -- why is there no feature to allow at least a time window for minimal editing of a bounty notice? The accidental awarding of bounty is also a real problem. **Meanwhile could you please fix my typos as a moderator?**

Comment: Mods don't have the ability, either, @EnglishStudent.

Comment: Thanks for the information anyway, @HDE226868 -- I was lucky it wasn't a major error, and will need to be meticulous while posting future bounties!

Answer (score 1):

To address "How do I edit the bounty notice to correct these errors?": you can't, unfortunately.  Sometimes typos and bad formatting only become apparent after the bounty is posted, and then it's too late.  I once saw a 2500-character bounty that was *submitted* with paragraphs and highlighting and suchlike -- all gone, and the person posting it couldn't get it fixed either.

I don't have a response to the feature request; I'm answering the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) question asked in the title.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, @Monica Cellio. We need a feature to allow the poster to edit the bounty notice for at least 10 minutes, because typos look bad in the bounty notice and can even possibly (though not in my case) distort the message or confuse the reader.

Comment: I think in the case of flat-out distortion a mod could cancel the bounty and the person could add it again. But I rather doubt that would actually happen.